# Changing the name of silverstripes 'mysite' folder

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm building my first silverstripe site and have a pretty basic question that I can't seem to find an answer for anywhere. Is there a way to rename the 'mysite' folder without having to hack core code? The only reason is that I straight up just don't like the name of that folder, I'd rather I could change it to the actual name of the site I'm developing. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

changing the `mysite` folder name to something different is perfectly valid. technically speaking, the mysite folder is nothing else than a module, which can have any name you want, as long as it doesn't collide with 'core folders' (assets, cms...)

see http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/trunk/topics/directory-structure

Comment: This doesn't seem to work now, looking through the install 'mysite' is hardcoded everywhere (SS 3.1.x)

Comment: @nbsp is that still the case?